# Django url patterns dont match

Tags: python, regex, django, get

i created a django app.

i want to match

```
example.com/hat/12
```

to

```
example.com/hat/?hat_id=12
```

i am trying to send that from a "get" form like this :

```
<form action="/hat/" method="get">
Hat numarası : <input type="text" name="hat_id" ><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Ara">
```

my hat url patterns :

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<hat_id>\d+)$', views.detay, name='detay'),
)
```

is there any better way for this beside craeating a new pattern to match ?

Comment: After submitting, do you want to redirect to `/hat/12`?

Comment: yes i want to redirect to /hat/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
def index(request):
   hat_id = request.GET.get('hat_id', None)
   if hat_id:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detay', args=[hat_id]))
```

Comment: `None` is the default return for `.get`, and the view takes a _keyword argument_, where you are passing a positional argument. Its easier to use the [`redirect` shortcut](http://django.me/redirect); which would turn your return into `return redirect('detay', hat_id=hat_id)`

Comment: thanks guys. it both works. but i think what burhan_khalid wrote is safer and shorter.